# Run a single Go file with a single local import without using modules

Tags: go, package, relative-path

I have a series of go files that are linked by use but are logically independent. They all use a common set of helper functions defined in a separate file.

My directory structure is shown below.

```
src/
├── foo1.go
├── foo2.go
├── ...
├── fooN.go
└── helper/
      └── helper.go
```

The **foox.go** files are all of this form -

```
package main

import help "./helper"

// functions and structs that use functionality in
// helper but are not related to anything going on
// in other foox.go files

func main() {
    // more things that uses functionality in helper
    // but are not related to anything going on in
    // other foox.go files

    return
}
```

I was running specific files with `go run foox.go`, but recently updated my version of Go. This workflow is now broken since relative imports are no longer permitted -

`"./helper" is relative, but relative import paths are not supported in module mode`

What is the correct the way to structure a collection independent Go files that all depend on the same collection of helper functions?

All the guidance says to use modules, but in this case that will mean having a separate module for each foox.go file where each file contains `func`s, `struct`s *etc.* that will never be used in any other module.

All I want to do is be able run a single .go file that includes another single local .go file without going through the hassle of making dozens of modules.

Comment: Use a single module. See   https://go.dev/doc/code for a tutorial.

Comment: I can't use a single module because the foox.go files contain conflicting func and struct names so they can't live in the same module.

Comment: move them to separate packages within the same module, or rename the symbols. This was never a supported workflow, so you’re always going to be fighting the tooling.

Comment: The conflicting func and struct names do not prevent the use of a single go.mod file.  Type this command `go mod init example.com` in the src directory.  Edit the files to import `"example.com/helper"`.   You can replace example.com with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable module mode by setting the environment variable `GO111MODULE=off`